# Can't setup Google Analytics for a Google Site

Tags: google-analytics

I had performed steps as described [here](http://www.google.com/support/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97459) , 24 hours passed but Analytics site still shows "Tracking Not Installed" status. Ideas?

Comment: Can you give me the link to the Google Site for debugging?

Comment: http://sites.google.com/site/testing328/

Comment: seemingly analytics loads but it does not report . I think you can follow what Drew says http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=49d5b624719688b8&hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, It started working. It seems my mistake was in setting site url as the full path, but it was necessary to set site url to "sites.google.com" part only.

Answer (score 0):

The last answer by Gombessa on this page should solve your problem: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=49d5b624719688b8&hl=en

Comment: I've tried it, but after 1 hour it shows "Tracking Not Installed" again. How I can check if Analytics is really installed on my site? I've found my web property id in the body of main page, but the code looks different - not the same as tracking code sample proposed on the GA site.